# solution of a quadratic equation

Tags: calculus

If I have an equation of a form:
$$x^2+\alpha x + 10 =0$$

my book says that both roots have the same sign because "10" is positive. I'm trying to understand why the book makes this claim. Is there some kind of a rule I can refer to?

Comment: Write your equation in the form $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$ and expand. What does the constant term tell you about the roots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a,b$ denotes the root of this polynomial. Then:

$x^{2}+\alpha x+10=(x-a)(x-b)=x^{2}-(a+b)x+ab$

so $ab=10>0$ so $a$ and $b$ have the same sign.

Answer (score 1):

If $p,q$ are the roots  using Vieta's formula:  $\displaystyle p+q=-\alpha,pq=10$

Now, the discriminant $D$ is $\alpha^2-40$

If $\displaystyle D<0, p,q$ are imaginary. For example $$x^2-4x+40=0\iff(x-2)^2=-36\iff x=2\pm6i$$

Else $p,q$ are real and $\displaystyle p=\dfrac{10}q$  which has the same sign as that of $q$